# Insert statement as part of stored proc not inserting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong with the insert statements I have created as part of this stored procedure. If I run them outside of the procedure with the variable declared they insert rows without issue. I'm assuming its a simple syntax issue that I am overlooking.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @SixMinCount int = 0
, @SixtyMinCount int = 0
, @Change float = 0.0
, @PercentThreshold float = 0.07
, @CountThreshold int = 900
, @QualityLogNote varchar(500) = ''

select @SixMinCount = COUNT(0)
from dbo.Company c
join dbo.CollectionSite cs with (nolock)
on cs.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
join dbo.SystemCode sc with (nolock)
on sc.SystemCodeId = c.CompanyStateCd
AND sc.SystemCodeTypeId = 12
where c.ActiveInd = 'Y' --only active sites
AND c.ApprovedInd = 'Y' --only approved sites
AND cs.OwningNetworkId = 32971 --fieldprint network
AND cs.TestSiteInd = 'N' --non test sites
AND (select MAX(convert(varchar,lsWorkstationRequest.CreatedDt,120)) from dbo.lsWorkstationRequest where lsWorkstationId = c.CompanyId) > DATEADD(MI, -6, GETDATE()) --has not connected within the last five minutes
AND c.CompanyNm not like 'fp%' --corporate stations and some demo/test stations that aren't marked as such

select @SixtyMinCount =  COUNT(0)
from dbo.Company c
join dbo.CollectionSite cs with (nolock)
on cs.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
join dbo.SystemCode sc with (nolock)
on sc.SystemCodeId = c.CompanyStateCd
AND sc.SystemCodeTypeId = 12
where c.ActiveInd = 'Y' --only active sites
AND c.ApprovedInd = 'Y' --only approved sites
AND cs.OwningNetworkId = 32971 --fieldprint network
AND cs.TestSiteInd = 'N' --non test sites
AND (select MAX(convert(varchar,lsWorkstationRequest.CreatedDt,120)) from dbo.lsWorkstationRequest where lsWorkstationId = c.CompanyId) > DATEADD(MI, -60, GETDATE()) --has not connected within the last five minutes
AND c.CompanyNm not like 'fp%' --coporate stations and some demo/test stations that aren't marked as such

IF (@SixMinCount < @CountThreshold )
begin
    return 1;  -- 1 denotes 'something is wrong'

        set @QualityLogNote = ('The total number of Sites connected is below the minimum threshold.'
        + Char(10) + char(13) + 'Sites Connected Number Threshold = '+ convert(varchar, @CountThreshold) + Char(10)+ Char(13) + 
        'Sites Currently Connected = ' + Convert(varchar, @SixMinCount))

        insert into QualityLog (NonconformityCd, OccuranceDt, ActiveInd, DeliveredInd, CorrectedInd, Notes)
        values ('FP-IT Site Alert', GetDate(), 'Y', 'N', 'N', @QualityLogNote) 
end
--ELSE
begin
    select @Change = (@SixtyMinCount-@SixMinCount)/1337.0--.0 to force sql server to use float



    if (@Change > @PercentThreshold)
    begin
        return 1;

            set @QualityLogNote = ('There has rapid change in the number of sites connecting in the past 6 minutes'
            + Char(10) + char(13) + 'Threshold for % change in number of sites connected = '+ convert(varchar, Cast(Cast((@PercentThreshold)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(5)) + '%') + Char(10)+ Char(13) + 
            'Percent change between cycles = ' + Convert(varchar, Cast(Cast((@Change)*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(5)) + '%'))

            insert into QualityLog (NonconformityCd, OccuranceDt, ActiveInd, DeliveredInd, CorrectedInd, Notes)
            values ('FP-IT Site Alert', GetDate(), 'Y', 'N', 'N', @QualityLogNote) 
    end
    else
    begin
        return 0; -- 0 denotes 'all is well'
    end
end
```

END

Comment: You should probably take a peek at this. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange I am aware, but Im a dev ops guy not trying to rock the boat, I know more experienced coders on the team have raised the issue with the lead dev already.

Comment: Ugh I don't envy that situation. I have seen the lead dev be staunch about splattering that all over the place against all advice. It almost always ends in a massive project to go through everything and get rid of it. But this is a discussion for another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `return 1;`, the procedure stops there.

If you want to insert the row then `return 1;` and not continue to the next section, then move the `return 1;` after the `insert`.

Comment: Just for fun, and if you are interested in AI, MIT has posted some lectures  http://www.openculture.com/2017/05/artificial-intelligence-a-free-online-course-from-mit.html

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Neat

Answer (score 2):

Comment out return 1 above the INSERT statements. The return command interrupts the logic flow, so the code after RETURN is not executed.